JPA transaction issued
check this out . i'm just testing transaction by making error ,i made error in the line    em.persist(enro);. and it should be jump into exception block, right?. instead of that it excute commit and ended the transaction. and then it don't go to next line i=1; it jumped into exception .and excuted until the rollback . when have reached rollback statement line, got error saying "No transaction is currently active". why? so rollback is useless?
public int addclassOrEnrollment(Enrollment enro, Boolean createClass) {
        int i=0;
        EntityManager em=null;
        try {em=ConnectionClass.getManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin(); // transaction was started successfully 
            if(createClass==true) {
                enro.getClassroom().setCreaterId(enro.getUser());;
            em.persist(enro.getClassroom());
            }
            em.persist(enro.getUser());
            System.out.println("error test 1");
            em.persist(enro); // here will occur error beause of trying to add FK without parent record in other table
            System.out.println("here is 2");
            em.getTransaction().commit();// at this line jumped to Exception block
            i=1; // this line didn't excute
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error :"+e.getMessage());// this line excuted
            
            System.out.println("next error");// this line excuted
                em.getTransaction().rollback(); // here i got error message saying "No transaction is currently active"
        
            
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally {
            if(em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
        
        return i;
        
    }

help and explain me . if i use like that, em.getTransaction().rollback() is useless because it went ot commit and transaction acive truned false although getting exception before commit;
} catch (Exception e) {
            if (em != null && em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            System.out.println("error :"+e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


Error happens on commit because persist is only add entity to Hibernate session and not insert it in DB.
When commit happens Hibernate try to insert and fails. This cause rollback and closing of the session.
I suggest you to execute commit in separate try catch section.

You have to flush your entities to the database after the persist :
em.flush

